# How to set python package search path in VSCode?

Tags: python, environment-variables, visual-studio-code, package

There is a python project whose launcher.sh contains

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:${TOP}/libs/:${TOP}/src
```

And The program runs well when running in vim. But when I run it in VS Code, get the error like `"ImportError:NO module named XXX"` as fellowing:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
ImportError: No module named configobj
```

Obviously, the reason is that package search path is not configged correctly. So, I set `envFile` in **launch.json** to `"${workspaceRoot}/.env"`, and create `.env` file in  workspaceRoot:

```
PYTHONPATH=${workspaceRoot}/libs:${workspaceRoot}/src:$PYTHONPATH
```

but the same error still occurs. So how can I set python packages search path environment variable correctly in VS Code?